# What are the MATLAB syntax for various neural network learning algorithms and activation functions??

Tags: matlab, neural-networks

I just started learning MATLAB for neural network implementation. I just studied the various activation functions. However, I am confused in their syntax. Please help...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I feel that you may post this query in a computer science forum..